# what will Allah get by creating humans?

Tags: quran, allah, creation

Understand my question carefully. I know that Allah doesn't need humans help or our worship doesn't benefit him but us. But why did he created humans or jins or angels? Is it because Allah just wants to or there is other reason? Is there any Hadith talk about this?

And also don't just answer my question by saying Allah created us to worship him. I know that. But Allah doesn't need our worship. I want to know what is the real reason Allah created us.

Answer (score 2):

Allah doesn't "get" anything. Allah has no needs. No one can benefit Allah in any way since He is perfect.

The whole question is, thus, wrong. Allah doesn't do things because he "gets" some benefit or fulfills some need out of it.

To try to understand why God did something is impossible except for what God tells us Himself. He told us He created us to worship Him. You will not get much more than that.

There is no practical use of knowing any more reason than what concerns us.

Answer (score 1):

Assalamualaikum ,this will be helpful inshallah.
https://youtu.be/vpRFKIIztbM

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I already watched that video. I already whatever Allah commands us to do it's for our own benefit. But my question is not that

Answer (score 0):

A better question would have been 'Why were humans created when Jinns existed?'.

Because Jinns are not capable of compassion, forgiveness and diligent obedience like humans are.

This is shown easily by the antics of Satan. He could, even now, simply ask God for forgiveness, show compassion to mankind and change his ways. That he doesn't and even God says he won't until the day of judgement, shows why humans are necessary, to prove Satan wrong.

Source [Islamiqate](https://www.islamiqate.com)